# Unable to save files or save downloads

Tags: updates

Unable to save files, or any downloads or add-ons; meaning each reboot wipes clean everything and all work previously done.

Comment: Are you live booting from a CD or USB drive?

Comment: How are you running Ubuntu? From a Live CD/DVD/USB medium? Where do you save your files that you want to persist across system restarts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running off of a USB drive that was set up using Startup Disc Creator or Unetbootin, make sure that when installing, you are using the "Reserved extra space" or "Space used to preserve files across reboots" options.

This will add a persistent file named casper-rw to the O/S, that will save changes.
Max size for this file is 4GB, if you need more persistence you can make a persistent ext partition named casper-rw.

With a persistent install it is still not recommended to do a software update and you will not be able to upgrade the kernel. You will be able to install programs and save settings.